# How to create a bootable usb stick on OS X

Tags: usb-creator

[Create a bootable USB stick on macOS | Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx)

When I get to the step of converting the .iso to an .img it continues to respond as such: " -bash: /Users/RidgeJohnston/Downloads/ubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso: Permission denied "

This is the command script I used:

`~ RidgeJohnston$ /Users/RidgeJohnston/Downloads/ubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso hdiutil convert -format UDRW -o ~/path/to/target.img ~/path/to/unbunto.iso`

How can I get passed this denied action and complete the processes?

Comment: Did you use `sudo` before the command?

Comment: This is the command script I used: " ~ RidgeJohnston$ /Users/RidgeJohnston/Downloads/ubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso hdiutil convert -format UDRW -o ~/path/to/target.img ~/path/to/unbunto.iso "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following command

`hdiutil convert -format UDRW -o ~/Downloads/ubuntu.img ~/Downloads/ubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso`

Use `sudo` before the command if required.

This will convert the iso file to an img file and save it as 'ubuntu.img' in your Downloads folder.

Run `diskutil list` and determine the device node assigned to the USB Drive eg- /dev/disk2

Now unmount this disk `diskutil unmountDisk /dev/diskN` where N should be replaced with the node number determined above eg- 2.

Now, write the image to the USB drive using the command

`sudo dd if=~/Downloads/ubuntu.img.dmg of=/dev/rdiskN bs=1m`

where N should be replaced with the node number.

Comment: It responded as such: " hdiutil: convert failed - No such file or directory "

Comment: Remove the /Users/RidgeJohnston from both paths in the command and try again. Answer has also been edited accordingly.

Comment: I used this code script: " hdiutil convert -format UDRW -o /Downloads/unbuntu.img /Downloads/unbuntu-14.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso " and it responded as such: " hdiutil: convert failed - No such file or directory "

Comment: It is ubuntu not unbuntu :-P Copy the command from the answer and run it in the terminal.

Comment: lol I complete overlooked the spelling. :/  Thank you for posting the script, it worked! Thank you!

Comment: Actually, one more question. My apology. I received this following script: " WARNING: Improper use of the sudo command could lead to data loss or the deletion of important system files. Please double-check your typing when using sudo. Type "man sudo" for more information. 

To proceed, enter your password, or type Ctrl-C to abort.

Password:
Sorry, try again.
Password: 
Sorry, try again
Password: 
Sorry, try again
sudo: 3 incorrect password attempts
ridge-johnstons-imac:~ Ridge Johnston$ " 

Does this mean the following?: 

1) The password is different than main log in?
2) Must start over?

Comment: `sudo` command grants elevated privileges and is required for certain tasks eg- the `dd` command. Enter the password which you have set for your user in OS X and press enter.

Comment: Okay, so I need to restart the process and use the login in for my admin user account?

Comment: No need to restart the process. I have edited the answer to add the remaining steps. When it asks for the password, enter the password which you use to log into your mac.

Comment: I realized that the conversion automatically established .dmg to the end of the file script registration "ubuntu.img", so it required ~/Downloads/ubuntu.img.dmg of=/dev/rdisk1 bs-1m " 

It should not have been this difficult for me. haha. 

Now I am correct to believe that after submitting the command request, a now response following it affirms the process as satisfactory and completed. Correct?